# How to send secondary variable to view with composer

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-5.4

In my composer I pass list of data as :

```
$evens = Even::all()->paginate(10);
$view->with('evens', $evens);
```

But now I want to also pass if the post is liked by the user or not with:

```
$likes = Inspiring::select('even_id')->where('user_id', Auth::user()->id)->get();
$likeArr = array_flatten($likes->toArray());
```

And than activate a class depending on if user liked the post or not

But when I use `with` I can only send one collection of data. I wonder how I can san this data as collection or pass it as adding `$likeArr` into `$even`

Comment: You can chain `with` or send an array. `$view->with('foo', $foo)->with('bar', $bar)` or `$view->with(['foo' => $foo, 'bar' => $bar])`

Comment: Great candidate for scoping method in model.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pass an array

```
return  $view->with(['evens' => $evens, 'likeArr' => $likeArr]);
```

Comment: Yeas it works, I didn't know I can add multiple a data inside `with`. Btw you forgot to put quotes for likeArr